# How to automate image rescaling done by PDF viewers?

Tags: pdf, images

I have a PDF that I would like to shrink for a presentation.  PDF viewers, like evince and Apple's Preview do a great job of zooming out.  How can I reproduce this type of zoom-out outside of the PDF viewers?  Ideally, I'd like a command line or other automatable solution.  Right now I am taking a screenshot of the zoomed out PDF viewer!

Here is an example of the type of rescaling  I am talking about:

[Original PDF](https://bitbucket.org/edmcman/edmcmanpub/src/c3757379e84682c47d6d64b19de2a9aa454fbc52/pdf-zoom/orig.pdf)

Screenshot at 100% zoom in evince:
[image: Screenshot of original PDF viewed in evince]

Screenshot at ~20% zoom in evince: (despite that evince says 50%).  This is what I would like to get as output:
[image: Screenshot of original PDF zoomed out]

Rescaled image using ImageMagick with `convert orig.pdf -resize '25%' convert-zoomout.png`.  Note how the lines are small and indistinct.  Unfortunately, scaling in Powerpoint produces similar results as this.
[image: Rescaled image with ImageMagick]

Comment: try with ghostscript

Comment: @Karan You should make that an answer.  I'd still prefer a free solution, but a non-free solution is better than no solution.

Comment: All right, done. I'll look around for a free alternative as well.

Comment: @Karan I will give some time to see if people know of any free alternatives, but if there are none I'll accept your answer.

Comment: While using ImageMagick, did you try specifying a higher [density](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density), higher [quality](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality), or even [auto-gamma](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-gamma)/[auto-level](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-level)?

Comment: @Karan I did try higher densities and qualities, and also alternate filters.  I did not try auto-gamma or auto-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [**Advanced PDF Tools Command Line**](http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201111/resize-pdf-page-content-using-command-line-13204.html) with a command like:

```
pdftools -i input.pdf -o output.pdf -j "25% 25% true"
```

gave me the following at 100% zoom:

[image: 1]

It's not free however, and the unregistered version only modifies half the pages of a PDF (in this case though it worked since there was only a single page).